# Moving an element surrounded by float left and right to next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I have a complicated header with lots of elements moved around with float: left and right. And they work nicely in desktop. However I want to achieve a responsive view where the navigation element is moved to the next line.

Here's an image to demonstrate:

[image]

Question is how can I push the menu element, which is in the middle, down to the next line while the others keep their positions.

Here's an extremely basic markup representation of the header at full view: http://jsfiddle.net/aAG2s/

```
 <header class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">Button 1</div>
    <div class="pull-left">Logo</div>
    <div class="pull-left menu">Menu</div>

    <div class="pull-right">Button 2</div>  
</header>
```

EDIT TO CLARIFY:

I am looking for a way without changing the order in which the html markup is.

Comment: Please do not "trick" the site by giving a block of code with nothing in it. Just include the code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using media queries:   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqbMc/12/)

```
     header {
     border: 1px solid black; 
     padding-bottom: 50px;}
.pull-left, .pull-right {
     border: 1px solid red; 
     padding: 5px; margin: 5px}
.menu {
     border: 1px solid blue;
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 50px;
     right: 0;
     left: 0px;}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .menu {
         position: relative;
         margin: 5px;
         width: auto;
     }
     header {
          padding-bottom: 0px;
}
}
```

Comment: The menu is outside the header :/

Comment: @Boaz, I know, I lost my edits, when I updated, feeling a little silly.  Just noticed the issue with the 98%, working on that.

Comment: @Boaz all fixed, including the 98% issue

Comment: This does indeed work nicely as long as the menu is fixed height, which is why I am marking it accepted. However in my project I am going with the javascript solution posted below because my menu will have variable height like bootstrap menu.

Comment: @elvista Fair enough, thanks for accepting.  If you require the header to have a responsive height, you can set padding-bottom as a percentage, and height to 0.  Padding-top and bottom calculate from the width of the containing parent, meaning you can create pure css responsive heights this way.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/aAG2s/2/

css

```
header {border: 1px solid black}
.pull-left, .pull-right {border: 1px solid red; padding: 5px; margin: 5px}
.menu {border: 1px solid blue}
.pull-left{float:left;}.pull-right{float:right;}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .menu{width:98%;}

}
```

html

```
<header class="clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left">Button 1</div>
        <div class="pull-left">Logo</div>


        <div class="pull-right">Button 2</div><div class="pull-left menu">Menu</div>
    </header>
```

Comment: +1 But note the change in the markup (changing the `menu` element to be the last child) might not be allowed by the OP's requirements.

Comment: Quiet. I was just looking for a way in which it can be done without moving the `div.menu`.

Comment: Also width:98% doesn't behave good if you keep decreasing the window size.

Comment: I used 98% because with 100% the border fell outside

Answer (score 1):

Place the menu last in the HTML and then clear the floating elements around it:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
    .menu{
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aAG2s/4/
I've added the red background just to emphasise it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using jquery can help...

http://jsfiddle.net/aAG2s/6/

```
p = $(".menu").detach();
$("#MainHeader").append(p);
```

Comment: This does help. Thanks!

Using it with .menu {clear:both;} works as a nice solution

Comment: Great! I think it is always better try a CSS solution, but when things go dirty, jQuery comes to the rescue! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/aAG2s/7/

```
header {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
.pull-left, .pull-right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.pull-right {
    margin-right:0;
}
.menu {
    border: 1px solid blue
}
.pull-left {
    float:left;
}
.pull-right {
    float:right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu {
        width:100%;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .pull-right {
        margin-top: -69px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
header {border: 1px solid black;position:relative;}
.pull-left, .pull-right {border: 1px solid red; padding: 5px; margin: 5px}
.menu {border: 1px solid blue;}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    header{min-height:100px;}
    .menu{        
        float:right !important;
        width:99%;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:0;
    }
}
```